# R: truncate strings to a word

Tags: r

I'm new to R, and trying to use it to truncate words in the headers of a spreadsheet to a word. For example:

```
Bacteria(100);Firmicutes(100);Clostridia(100);Clostridiales(100);Lachnospiraceae(100);unclassified(100);

Bacteria(100);Tenericutes(100);Mollicutes(100);Mollicutes_RF9(100);unclassified(100);unclassified(100);
```

So I would like to shorten the taxon to a single word without the numbers: like Clostridia and Mollicutes. I think it can be done, but can't figure how.

Thanks.

Comment: Please give us a code

Comment: `strsplit(str, '\\(\\d+\\);\\n*')[[1]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `sub`

```
sub("\\(.*", "", "Firmicutes(100)")
```

Suppose, we read the data in 'R' using `read.csv/read.table` with `check.names=FALSE`, then we apply the same code on the column names

```
colnames(data) <- sub("\\(.*", "", colnames(data))
```

If it is a single string

```
library(stringr)
 str1 <- "Bacteria(100);Firmicutes(100);Clostridia(100);Clostridiales(100);Lachnospiraceae(100);unclassified(100)"

str_extract_all(str1, "[^()0-9;]+")[[1]]
#[1] "Bacteria"        "Firmicutes"      "Clostridia"      "Clostridiales"   "Lachnospiraceae"
#[6] "unclassified"
```

#### Update

Suppose if we need to extract the third word i.e. "Clostridia"

```
sub("^([^(]+[(][^;]+;){2}(\\w+).*", "\\2", str1)
#[1] "Clostridia"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Though I don't fully understand all those \\[]"", I assume what you are doing is to split those words apart. And how do I replace the 'Clostridia or Mollicutes' over 'Bacteria(100);Firmicutes(100);Clostridia(100);Clostridiales(100);Lachnospiraceae(100);unclassified(100);'?

Comment: @SoonHweeN  Here, I am matching the substring that start with `\\(` to the end of the string `.*` - i.e. one or more charcters and replace it with `'''`

Comment: Thanks, akrun. Got that part now. But I'm trying to use the 3rd word as the column name. Any way to sub that in, regardless of what that word might be? As different columns will have different names.

Comment: @SoonHweeN   Did you meant to extract `Clostridia`

Comment: Saw the update. Yea, but replacing, instead of extracting, is what I have in mind. Like a hundred columns with different names similar to the example, and I would like to rename them with the 3rd word. Hope this clarifies. Thanks!!

Comment: @SoonHweeN  I am not sure I understand it properly

Comment: Currently in an excel cell, the column name is 'Bacteria(100);Firmicutes(100);Clostridia(100);Clostridiales(100);Lachnospiracea‌​e(100);unclassified(100);'. I wish to change to 'Clostridia', the 3rd word.

Comment: @SoonHweeN  That is what I got

Answer (score 0):

Using only base commands, the names can be extracted with this code:

```
nam <- c("Bacteria(100);Tenericutes(100);Mollicutes(100);Mollicutes_RF9(100);unclassified(100);unclassified(100);")
nam <- strsplit(nam, ";")[[1]]
nam <- unname(sapply(nam, FUN=function(x) sub("\\(.*", "", x)))

nam
[1] "Bacteria"       "Tenericutes"    "Mollicutes"     "Mollicutes_RF9" "unclassified"   "unclassified"
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need? Or did I completely misunderstood?

```
gsub('\\(.*\\)', '', unlist(strsplit(x, ';'))[3])
#[1] "Clostridia"
```

where `x` is your column name

Comment: I don't really understand the first line. Is that trying to isolate the 3rd word delimited by ";"?

Comment: "Bacteria(100);Firmicutes(100);Clostridia(100);Clostridiales(100);Lachnospiraceae(100);unclassified(100)" is the column name. Sorry, I'm still learning R, so those operators are still strange to me.

Comment: Yes! It did replace with Clostridia. But it appeared ;"Clostridia" in excel. Is it possible to remove the ; and " " with your command? Or I should do another gsub()?

Comment: When you do it in `R`, is the result the one you want exactly?

Comment: Yes, it is what I want. Clostridia, or whatever that is the 3rd word, to be the column name.

Comment: Then it is an excel issue I guess...maybe if you saved it as csv?

Comment: Yea, I saved as csv. So I should save in other format to remove that issue?

Comment: I thought csv would be ok. don't know...first time I hear this. Maybe if you try to remove them in excel somehow?

Comment: Alright. But the main problem is solved. Thank you very much!